# If I get the TAL documents for the rent increase, does it mean I can unlikely file a challenge to the rent increase of my apartment in Quebec?

Tags: canada, rent

If I get the TAL documents for the rent increase, does it mean I can unlikely file a challenge to the rent increase of my apartment in Quebec? There was work done, but most of the work on my apartment was done a year ago, and the rest of the renovation touched the roof, the swimming pool, the parking lot, so I am wondering if you can challenge it in court. They provided me with the papers, and it seems to be in line with what the minimum rent increase should be. Not sure if it's worth challenging this in court.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it this is a condominium or co-op. Assuming so:

Maintenance work on shared infrastructure, whether it happens to be a part of the property you use or not, maintains the value of your unit, and is a standard part of the property maintenance fees. The only way you can opt out of it is to sell and move elsewhere.

At some point they'll repair something important to you and not to your neighbor, and it will be their turn to grumble. Over time it all pretty much averages out.

You knew this, or should have known it, when you signed the purchase agreement. If you really didn't know, that's because you didn't read the paperwork before signing it, and that's nobody's fault but your own.

(If it's a straight rental, then unless you can show that the price increase is unreasonable, you have the same options: accept it or move out. If you *do* think it's unreasonable, you need to talk to a lawyer who knows your local legal environment to find out if there's any way to challenge it.)

Answer (score 0):

The landlord doesn't have to provide the [calculation](https://www.tal.gouv.qc.ca/en/news/detail?code=calculation-of-the-2024-rent-adjustment). That he is, means he expects you to be skeptical and is showing his costs.

If you would like to challenge it, there is a simple form to fill out and get him to sign it or send by registered mail.  You have 30 days from receipt of the notice to reply.  Then there will be a hearing where the landlord will have to provide receipts.  The regie will calculate the correct amount for the increase.  If it's in line with the landlords calculation then you will probably have to pay the costs (~87$).

If you're a good tenant it's a better idea to call and negotiate with the landlord, but with a 1.5% vacancy rate - good luck.